# Editor Plugin - Breaks when toggling between Visual to Text

Tags: plugin-development

I've developed a plugin that inserts shortcode, now I want to reverse the process.
I've got it to find and replace the shortcode with an image. I've got it so when you hover over the image it puts an overlay with links to open an editor window to edit,etc... which only works onload (it breaks toggling between Visual and Text and back) it doesn't add the overlay.

I'm using

```
   editor.on( 'BeforeSetContent', function(event) {
         event.content = replaceShortcodes(event.content);
         generateOverlay(editor)
   });

    editor.on( 'PostProcess', function(event) {
         if (event.get) {
            event.content = restoreShortcodes(event.content);
         }
    });
```

I'm using JQuery to generate the hover over overlay(unless anyone has another way)
 using

```
function generateOverlay(editor){
        //event.preventDefault();
        if(!$("#content_ifr").contents().find('.wp-ip-image').parent().hasClass("wp-ip-container")){
            $("#content_ifr").contents().find('.wp-ip-image').parent().wrap('<div class="wp-ip-container" data-mce-bogus="1" contenteditabl="false"></div>')
        }
var wp_ip_img = $("#content_ifr").contents().find('.wp-ip-image')

            wp_ip_img.hover(
                        function(){
                            post_id = $(this).data('post-id');
                            blog_id = $(this).data('blog-id');

                            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                            $(this).before('<div id="wp-ip-div-'+blog_id+'-'+post_id+'" class="wp-ip-overlay"></div>')
                            $(this).parent().find("#wp-ip-div-"+blog_id+"-"+post_id).hover(
                                function(){

                                $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
                                $(this).html(getPostData(post_id,blog_id))
                                $(this).find('.wp-preview-ip').unbind().click(function(e){

                                    postContent(editor,$(this).data('url'));
                                });
                                $(this).find('.wp-remove-ip').unbind().click(function(e){
                                    $("#content_ifr").contents().find("#wp-ip-div-"+blog_id+"-"+post_id).parent().remove()
                                });
                                $(this).find('.wp-edit-ip').unbind().click(function(e){
                                    insertPosts(editor,blog_id,post_id,wp_ip_img.data('wp-insert-post'))
                                });

                                },
                                function(){
                                    $(this).remove()
                                    $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
                                }
                            );              
                        },
                        function(){
                            $(this).css('cursor', 'default');
                        }
            );

    }`
```

when I toggle to Visual it replaces the shortcode then runs `generateOverlay(editor)` it gets to `wp_ip_img.hover(...` and doesnt run beyond even though it can find `wp_ip_img`

if anyone has any ideas

Comment: This looks like you're recreating the functionality of blocks, have you considered using the block editor and creating your own block?

Comment: At the moment we are not using Gutenberg, that's phase 2! I've got a lot of users editing the sites, so I cant just change it over